# Adding Transform CSS property to div modifies its border-radius

Tags: css, border-radius

I have 2 div elements: a parent and its child, and need to have rounded corners on both of them. Setting `border-radius` to for example `20px` usually does that, but once I add transform property to child specifically `scaleX`, `border-radius` becomes smaller and visually doesn't change even if I set its value to higher, here is the sample code:

```css
.container {
  background-color: grey;
  height: 20px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 20px;
}

.item {
  background-color: red;
  transform-origin: 0 50%;
  transform: scaleX(0.5);
  border-radius: 20px;
  height: inherit;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```

and here's the codesandbox link of the following code:
https://codesandbox.io/s/silent-worker-nt7i0v?file=/src/styles.css

and the image of the behavior:
Note how border radius of the child looks different than that of the parent, even though they have the same value set for it.

[image]

Comment: don't use transform in this case, consider width (width:50% )

Comment: yeah I'm using width for now, but was going to use transform and translate for animations, like the progress bar getting filled not sure if i can achieve that with just width?

Comment: You absolutely can do this sort of animation with just width.  The scale transform is going to stretch the image.  It wouldn't be possible to maintain the aspect ratio... at least not without also impacting the height at the same time (which does not appear to be your desire).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can definitely use width here, and you can definitely animate it too. Here's a quick example:

```css
.container {
  background-color: grey;
  height: 20px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 20px;
}

.item {
  background-color: red;
  width: 0%;
  border-radius: 20px;
  height: inherit;
  animation: fill 5s infinite;
}

@keyframes fill {
  from {
    width: 0%;
  }
  to {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the transform X is "squishing" the `.item`, and that's what you're seeing here.  As an alternative, can you use `width: 50%` instead of `transform: scaleX(0.5)`?  That will maintain the proper radius on `.item`

Answer (score 0):

scaleX is squishing the .item div, if you would like to use transform especially you can fix like that but using animation or width could be better.

```
.item {
  background-color: red;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  border-radius: 20px;
  height:inherit;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I think your code so complicated.

You can use simply `width` instead `transform`, `transform-origin`.

Just set simply like this.

```
.item {
  background-color: red;
  width: 50%;
  border-radius: 20px;
  height: inherit;
}
```